# bootstrap how to put something in the middle of a footer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i am using bootstrap and i have figured out how to put stuff on the right and left hand side of my footer, but i am not sure how to stick something in the middle

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
            <div class="logo1">
                <p style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 900; color: #F8BD23;">here</p>
                <p>a,<br>
                b,<br>
                c,<br>
                d<br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
            <a href="a"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a><a href="b"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-text > a {
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
}

.logo1 p {
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Sorry just to clear up confusion, i want 3 columns basically So it should look like

```
Col 1            Col 2                        Col 3
```

Comment: In other words, you want the "here", "a", "b", "c", "d" to all be center-aligned?

Comment: The best practice is to use 3 columns under a single row that will be contained within the footer. Pulling left and right the footer will not give you good results as far as dividing your footer into left, centre and right is concerned.

Comment: @NikosGatzoulis perfect thank u so much , just figured it out is well :) haha x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my own problem i guess just used a row and stuck 3 coloums in ,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Had no idea i could use that in the footer, thanks again for the help x

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Adding the **"text-center"** class to the container. So you will end up with this:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <p class="text-muted credit" style="color:#fff">xyz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```